# ember route switch template use handlebars if, is available?

Tags: templates, ember.js, render, routes

How to use route as a judgement?

just that for example:

if current route is `index.signup` so this code `{{#link-to 'index.signup'}}signup{{/link-to}}` will action.

---

```
{{#if routeNameisSomething}}

{{#link-to 'index.signup'}}signup{{/link-to}}

{{else}}

{{#link-to 'index.login'}}login{{/link-to}}

{{/if}}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. If you want an answer to your question, you're going to have to revise it to actually ask a question.

Comment: I just want to write the code above in the `index template`, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/titabaxe/7/edit